# Allow SDL to bypass X server under Linux

Tags: c++, sdl

In my attempt to make a simple game using SDL under Linux, I noticed that using the normal X11 back-end, it runs at about 60 FPS at 800x600x32, and drops at 20 FPS or so at 1024x768x32, which is a quite massive drop for a simple 2D game with a sprite and some 32x32 tiles. I've done some researches and found out that X server doesn't allow his clients to directly access the video hardware, forcing the program to use software surfaces, and many CPU cycles. Some of the provided solutions said to set the envvar SDL_VIDEODRIVER to "dga", and to use the XFree86 DGA driver to bypass the X server. I've installed the DGA dev packages libxxf86dga-dev (under Ubuntu), but when a try this:

```
putenv("SDL_VIDEODRIVER=dga");

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1)
{
    std::cout << "Init video error" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}
```

the program just exits with a "No available video device" error. I've given it superuser permissions, but it didn't help. Any ideas? Is this method still working, or are there other solutions besides switching to OpenGL? I'm using SDL 1.2.

Comment: You say the program exits with an error, what error is that?

Comment: From a quick look on Google it looks like OpenGL is the recommended way to get hardware acceleration. Dga also seems to have several drawbacks, the run as superuser is the most glaring one to me, but bad driver support seems to also be an issue.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg sorry, forgot to mention. The error is "No available video device".

Comment: @r_ahlskog well, from what I've seen in many 2D games created with SDL, they use the DGA driver, and that's why trying to run those games on my machine caused the same error. I'd like to avoid learning OpenGL for a game so simple.

Comment: @Narrakan: I am by no means an expert in DGA or anything, I am just an advanced Google filter in this area. However I found [this](http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-devel/2009-September/002060.html) which indicates that DGA for other than mouse input may no longer be available.

Comment: Are you using [`SDL_DisplayFormat()`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_DisplayFormat)?

Comment: @r_ahlskog mmh, interesting, anyway I've moved my project to OpenGL: it's much easier than I thought (at least regarding 2D drawing) and it runs about 1000% faster (more than 200 FPS at higher screen resolutions, and I even had to set a cap). So, not a problem anymore.

Comment: @genpfault yep, actually `SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha()` to avoid problems with .png transparency

Answer (score 0):

You might consider those questions

- Do you render to a hardware buffer ? (The SDL_HWSURFACE flag)
- All sprites & tiles are on the same surface ?
- Do you store tiles & sprites on a hardware surface ?
- The surface that hold tiles & sprites have the same pixel format as the one used by the video display ?

Comment: I do not render to a hardware buffer because X server doesn't allow access to it.The sprites and tiles are on two different surfaces and are blittered on the screen when needed. And yes, the surfaces are not hardware and are the same format.

Comment: You might still try with SDL_HWSURFACE, if you do pure blitting and no pixel level things. It can make a difference, actual experience. Also, I found out that rendering to 16 bits when the display is 32 bits give you a serious speed hit.

Comment: I tried using the SDL_HWSURFACE flag, but when I check the current flags after calling the `SDL_SetVideoMode()` function with those flags, it simply return `SDL_SWSURFACE`. As for the 16 bits rendering, I've not yet tried it.

Comment: Argh, ok, then indeed it sounds doomed for SDL 1.2. SDL 1.3 offers OpenGL-backed blitting out of the box, if you use 1.3 new API. For the 16 bits, no, it's the contrary, I noted that rendering in 16 bits is a perf. killer if the video is 32 bits  ^^

Comment: Well, maybe I'll give a look at 1.3 APIs, even if they're not yet production-ready. Thanks anyway ^^